# Check whether list of number is sequential or not

Tags: java

I have quite a layman question about Java programming.

I would like to write a function to check whether a list of number is sequential or not.

Say [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], the function will return true,

but for [1, 3, 4, 9, 10], the function will return false.

Could anyone help me?

Thank so much!

Answer (score 3):

Write a loop that looks at each element of the list.

For each position `i` in the list, test that list<sub>i</sub> + 1 equals list<sub>i + 1</sub>.

You can code it yourself as an exercise.  (Don't forget to deal with the edge cases ...)

---

**UPDATE:** ... for people treating this problem as a learning exercise.

A simple direct implementation approach is probably the best idea; e.g. @Joe's final answer.  However, the simple approach doesn't always work well ... or at all:

- Some Java `List` implementations have a `get` method that is `O(N)`.  That would lead to an `O(N^2)` algorithm overall.
- Sometimes a a list can only be accessed using an iterator; i.e. `list.get(i)` might not be an option.

In such cases, you could implement the algorithm with one pass through the list using an iterator.  You need to keep "the previous element" in variable, etcetera.

Answer (score 0):

Logic is simple. Just get the first number and check whether it matches with the next value. Like that check adjacent values. Break if the condition fails at any point. The list will be sequential if all the if condition is true.

Answer (score 0):

As Stephen C said, it is a very simple logic

```
int a[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5,7 };
        boolean flag = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length - 1; i++) {
            if (a[i + 1] != a[i] + 1) {
                flag = false;
                break;

            }
        }
        System.out.println("Flag is " + flag);
```

Comment: Close ... but no cigar :-)

Comment: (Hint: the question does not state that the first element of the list will always be 1.)

Comment: Not clear on why it won't work.   See the complete main method here and test it yourself  public static void main(String args[]) {
  int a[] = {  2, 3, 4, 5,6 };
  boolean flag = true;
  for (int i = a[0]; i < a.length - 1; i++) {
   if (a[i + 1] != a[i] + 1) {
    flag = false;
    break;

   }
  }
  System.out.println("Flag is " + flag);

 }

Comment: Try it with `{7, 8, 10}` :-)

Comment: Got it.   Modified the program as i=0.